# Could we have a "belongs on a different…"->electronics.SE close reason?

Tags: feature-request, on-topic, close-reasons

There have been several questions that revolve around e.g. wave propagation in waveguides, antenna array factors, noise in electronic systems etc.

Though most of them are pretty clearly "better off" on electronics.SE (because the experts there focus on the –well– electronic side of the signal) and not really on-topic here (because they don't concern themselves with processing or theory of signals), it's often unnecessarily complex to convey that notion to the asker:

> "It's RF signals!"

Since EE is clearly the closest-related engineering field to this site, could we have the delegation to that site as option (we so far only have meta.signals, which rarely is useful):

[image: Migration dialogue]

This should be listing an electronics.stackexchange.com option, too.

Same argument, by the way, can be made for math and stats.

The **benefit** to the folks asking would be a direct path to the right site, and for us, an easier way to kindly express "please go where this is more on-topic" without having to invest commenting time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any site that is not still in beta can request up to five user-initiated migration targets that will be set up by the Community Team as needed. There's a nice [FAQ about migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) over on the main meta site. You can request these through a meta request like this and we will consider them.

For right now, I don't see a need for this migration path.

The last time one of your moderators [migrated a question to Electrical Engineering was over a year ago](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) and over the last 90 days, only two questions have [close reasons](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) mentioning Electrical Engineering as the appropriate topic. I'm basing this on data available in the [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) available to all users with 10k or more reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think your statistics might be misleading however: the lack of clear migration path for the users leads to lack of visibility of the option. I'd simply never come up with the idea of tasking a moderator with migrating something – I just "talked the user into" migrating, or simply closed as generally off-topic.

Comment: So start closing with custom reasons. That's why you have the option of writing your own text. It helps us see when things like this are needed and helps moderators see when it might be useful to create a new site-specific close reason. The fact that no mod has felt the need to migrate a question in a year is somewhat telling, though.

Comment: But, we're quite hesitant to set these up without evidence of need. The thing is, getting people to reask on another site is a win in my book. There are side effects of migration that are problematic and confusing for new users. For example, if you migrate something and it gets closed, it gets bounced back here. If they ask the question there, it stays there and can be improved and reopened without bouncing around.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the response!  I wasn't aware of this option...

Comment: @Catija very right! OK, I think we can work with that. Also, I might presume Peter won't be upset when I occasionally flag for mod attention when I'm fairly certain a question would be a **good** fit for a different site without further editing.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, @MarcusMüller :) Feel free to ping me in a few months if you still think this is needed and we can reconsider!

Comment: @Catija will do!

Answer (score 1):

There are only three custom close reasons allowed, and these are currently set up to be:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I asked for the last one to be added, because the beginning of each northern hemisphere academic year always brings students asking for us to do their homework.

As a moderator, when I select the off-topic option, I can search for a more appropriate SE site:

[image]

but then when a mod does this, it automatically migrates it.

I'm not sure what it shows a high-rep user like you, Marcus.

Let me know if you think one of those three items can be replaced with your suggestion.  I'm just not sure it's possible to flag it for migration too. That's always up to the mods.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification: The same Migration dialog should contain the predefined option for electronics.SE, as we normal users can't search for sites.

Comment: @MarcusMüller hmm. Let me see if it’s possible to add a list of “usual suspect” migration sites...

Comment: That would be $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac 1\epsilon$ cool! (It'd be so cool, it diverged.)